# How to access .txt file using tcl PROC function

Tags: tcl

I have two files and I am comparing specific lines between two files using the def function.

```
def readPinFile(filename): 

   result = None
   with open(filename, "r") as file:    

    result = {}
    lastPin = None        
    for line in file:
        lines = line.strip()
        
        if lines[:3] == "PIN": 
            lastPin = lines.split(" ")[1]               
            result[lastPin] = {"LAYER": None, "RECT": None}
        
        if lines[:5] == "LAYER":
            result[lastPin]["LAYER"] = lines.split(" ")[1]
           
        if lines[:4] == "RECT":
            result[lastPin]["RECT"] = lines.split(" ")

return result

pin_of_file1 = readPinFile("osi_hbmp_top_briscm_1.lef") #lef file1
pin_of_file2 = readPinFile("osi_hbmp_top_briscm_2.lef")#lef file2
```

comparing between pins

```
with open("file04.txt", "r+") as output_file4:  #compare same pins with layer and location
 for pin, pin_data in pin_of_file1.items():
      if pin in pin_of_file2:
         if pin_of_file2[pin]["LAYER"] == pin_data["LAYER"] and pin_of_file2[pin]["RECT"] == pin_data["RECT"]:
             output_file4.write(pin + "\n\n")
```

The TCL code I tried to get the same output

```
proc fileinput {filename} {
set filedata [open filename r]
set file1 [ read $filedata ]
foreach line [split $file1 \n] {
      set pindata { PIN { LAYER {} RECT {} }}
      if {[string match *PIN* $line]} {
          dict lappend pindata PIN $line         
         }
      if {[string match *LAYER* $line]} {
           dict lappend pindata PIN {LAYER{$line}} 
         } 
      if {[string match *RECT* $line]} {
           dict lappend pindata PIN {RECT{$line}}
          } 
      }
  return $pindata
}
set fileinput1 [fileinput osi_hbmp_top_briscm_1.txt]
set fileinput2 [fileinput osi_hbmp_top_briscm_2.txt]
```

In tcl I am trying to write comparing between the pins section, but I am stuck in the middle. i am fully confused  to continue this code

```
    foreach $pin, $pin_data [gets $fileinput1]
        if{[string match $pin $fileinput2]}
```

This is the code I tried

Comment: @JHBonarius any comments?

Comment: try this : `fileinput osi_hbmp_top_briscm_1.txt` (note the space between your command and your string file)

Comment: I also think you want to return the dictionary value rather than your file : replace `return $file1` by `return $pindata`

Comment: @Mkn as per your suggestion, changes I did and got some errors on **proc** call           The changes updated on the question

Comment: filename is a `variable` in Tcl , you should set like this : [open `$filename` r]

Answer (score 1):

The error trace tells you the immediate problem:

```
couldn't open "filename": no such file or directory                     
    while executing                     
"open filename r"                      
    (procedure "fileinput" line 2)
```

You need to give the name of the file, not the name of the variable containing the file name. Tcl cares about whether things are uses or references/names a lot. You fix this by using:

```
    set filedata [open $filename r]
```

in the procedure; the added `$` is *vital* as it says "read from the variable and use its value here".

Comment: The `r` mode flag is optional; it does exactly what `open` would do without it.